# Raylib strange character movement

Tags: c, raylib

In this code, I want the character to move across a maze like map. I drew the map using map array. I could finally make the character not move through the walls and stop behind walls. But the problem is sometimes the character stops in random place. Then I use another input to move it to another place and it works. But when I press input keys again it moves in really fast speed. I haven't tried using CollisionDetectRecs() but I want that code to work. I'm a beginner.Please help. (Sorry for my english)

```
#include "raylib.h"
#include "raymath.h"
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<stdio.h>

// Global Variables
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 700
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 700
#define CHAR_WIDTH 32
#define CHAR_HEIGHT 32

#define MAP_ROWS 22
#define MAP_COLS 22

#define WALL_HEIGHT 32
#define WALL_WIDTH 32

typedef struct Player {
    Texture2D run_animation;
    Texture2D idle_animation;
    Vector2 position;
    Vector2 dir;
    float speed;
    bool is_moving;
} Player;

void DrawStartScreen(bool* game_running)
{
    Music bing_chilling_song = LoadMusicStream("assets/Oogway_Ascends.mp3");
    PlayMusicStream(bing_chilling_song);
    SetMusicVolume(bing_chilling_song, 0.5f);
    bool playing_music = true;

    while (*game_running)
    {
        // Check for quit button press
        if (WindowShouldClose())
        {
            *game_running = false;
            break;
        }

        if (IsKeyPressed(KEY_ENTER)) 
            break;

        if (IsKeyPressed(KEY_SPACE))
        {
            if (playing_music){
                PauseMusicStream(bing_chilling_song);
                playing_music = false;
            }
            else{
                ResumeMusicStream(bing_chilling_song);
                playing_music = true;
            }
        }

        // Update music stream
        UpdateMusicStream(bing_chilling_song);

        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(BLACK);

        DrawText("Press ENTER to start game", GetScreenWidth()/2 - MeasureText("Press ENTER to start game", 20)/2, GetScreenHeight()/2 - 50, 20, WHITE);
        DrawText("Press SPACE to pause/resume music", 10, 420, 20, MAROON);
        DrawText("-Music-", 720, 400, 20, RAYWHITE);
        DrawText("Oogway Ascends by Hams Zimmer", 562, 430, 15, RAYWHITE);
            
        EndDrawing();
    }
}

void game_over(bool* game_running, int score){
    Music game_over_sad_song = LoadMusicStream("assets/game_over.mp3");
    PlayMusicStream(game_over_sad_song);
    SetMusicVolume(game_over_sad_song, 1);
    while(*game_running){
        while(!WindowShouldClose()){
            *game_running = false;
            break;
        }
        UpdateMusicStream(game_over_sad_song);
        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(BLACK);

        DrawText("Game Over", GetScreenWidth()/2 - MeasureText("Game Over",30)/2, GetScreenHeight()/2 - 50, 30, WHITE);

        EndDrawing();
    }  
}

int main(void)
{
    // Initialization
    InitWindow(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, "Sprite Test");
    InitAudioDevice();
    SetTargetFPS(60);

    Player* player = (Player*)malloc(sizeof(Player));
    // Load sprite sheet texture
    player->run_animation = LoadTexture("assets/Run(32x32).png");
    player->idle_animation = LoadTexture("assets/Idle(32x32).png");
    //load wall sprite
    Texture2D wall_texture = LoadTexture("assets/Tile_72.png");
    player->dir.x = 0;
    player->dir.y = 0;

    Vector2 wall_position;
    Rectangle wall_dest = {0, 0, WALL_WIDTH, WALL_HEIGHT};

    //variables for collision check
    Vector2 new_position;
    int new_row;
    int new_col;

    //map array nooooooo tooo muccccch
    int map[22][22] = {
       {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
       {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
       {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
       {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
       {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
       {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
       {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
       {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
       {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
       {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
       {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
       {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
       {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
       {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
       {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
       {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
       {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
       {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
       {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
       {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
       {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
       {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
    };

    // Define animation frames
    //array of Rectangle
    //12 elements inside the array because twleve animation state
    Rectangle frames[12] = {
        { 0, 0, CHAR_WIDTH, CHAR_HEIGHT },
        { CHAR_WIDTH, 0, CHAR_WIDTH, CHAR_HEIGHT },
        { CHAR_WIDTH*2, 0, CHAR_WIDTH, CHAR_HEIGHT },
        { CHAR_WIDTH*3, 0, CHAR_WIDTH, CHAR_HEIGHT },
        { CHAR_WIDTH*4, 0, CHAR_WIDTH, CHAR_HEIGHT },
        { CHAR_WIDTH*5, 0, CHAR_WIDTH, CHAR_HEIGHT },
        { CHAR_WIDTH*6, 0, CHAR_WIDTH, CHAR_HEIGHT },
        { CHAR_WIDTH*7, 0, CHAR_WIDTH, CHAR_HEIGHT },
        { CHAR_WIDTH*8, 0, CHAR_WIDTH, CHAR_HEIGHT },
        { CHAR_WIDTH*9, 0, CHAR_WIDTH, CHAR_HEIGHT },
        { CHAR_WIDTH*10, 0, CHAR_WIDTH, CHAR_HEIGHT },
        { CHAR_WIDTH*11, 0, CHAR_WIDTH, CHAR_HEIGHT }
    };

    // Define animation variables
    int currentFrame = 0;
    int frameCounter = 0;
    int frameSpeed = 5;

    // Define character variables
    player->position.x = 32;
    player->position.y = 32;
    player->speed = 2.0f;
    player->is_moving = false;

    // Disable ESC key quit
    SetExitKey(KEY_NULL);

    bool game_running = true;
    bool wall_collision = false;
    DrawStartScreen(&game_running);

    // Main game loop
    while (game_running && !WindowShouldClose())
    {
        // Update animation frame
        frameCounter++;
        if (frameCounter >= frameSpeed)
        {
            frameCounter = 0;
            currentFrame++;
            if (currentFrame > 11) 
            currentFrame = 0;
        }
        // Draw current animation frame and character position
        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(SKYBLUE);
        //Rectangle source = (Rectangle){0, 0, 32, 32};
        for (int i = 0; i < MAP_ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < MAP_COLS; j++) {
                if (map[i][j] == 1) {
                    wall_position.x = j * WALL_WIDTH;
                    wall_position.y = i * WALL_HEIGHT;
                    wall_dest = (Rectangle){ wall_position.x, wall_position.y, WALL_WIDTH, WALL_HEIGHT };
                    DrawTextureRec(wall_texture, wall_dest, (Vector2){wall_position.x,wall_position.y}, WHITE);
                }
            }
        }
        // Handle keyboard input
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_RIGHT)){
            new_position = (Vector2){player->position.x + player->speed, player->position.y};
            new_row = (int)(new_position.y / WALL_HEIGHT);
            new_col = (int)((new_position.x + CHAR_WIDTH) / WALL_WIDTH);
            if (map[new_row][new_col] == 1) {
                // There is a wall at the new position, so don't move the player
                player->position.x = new_col * WALL_WIDTH - CHAR_WIDTH + 1;
            } else {
                // No wall at the new position, so move the player
                player->position = new_position;
                player->is_moving = true;
            }
        }
        else if (IsKeyDown(KEY_LEFT)){
            new_position = (Vector2){player->position.x - player->speed, player->position.y};
            new_row = (int)(new_position.y / WALL_HEIGHT);
            new_col = (int)((new_position.x - CHAR_WIDTH) / WALL_WIDTH);
            if (map[new_row][new_col] == 1) {
                // There is a wall at the new position, so don't move the player
                player->position.x = new_col * WALL_WIDTH + CHAR_WIDTH - 1;
            } else {
                // No wall at the new position, so move the player
                player->position = new_position;
                player->is_moving = true;
            }
        }
        else if (IsKeyDown(KEY_DOWN)) {
            new_position = (Vector2){player->position.x, player->position.y + player->speed};
            new_row = (int)((new_position.y + CHAR_HEIGHT) / WALL_HEIGHT);
            new_col = (int)(new_position.x / WALL_WIDTH);
            if (map[new_row][new_col] == 1) {
                // There is a wall at the new position, so don't move the player
                player->position.y = new_row * WALL_HEIGHT - CHAR_HEIGHT + 1;
            } else {
                // No wall at the new position, so move the player
                player->position = new_position;
                player->is_moving = true;
            }
        }
        else if (IsKeyDown(KEY_UP)){
            new_position = (Vector2){player->position.x, player->position.y - player->speed};
            new_row = (int)((new_position.y - CHAR_HEIGHT) / WALL_HEIGHT);
            new_col = (int)(new_position.x / WALL_WIDTH);
            if (map[new_row][new_col] == 1) {
                // There is a wall at the new position, so don't move the player
                player->position.y = new_row * WALL_HEIGHT + CHAR_HEIGHT - 1;
            } else {
                // No wall at the new position, so move the player
                player->position = new_position;
                player->is_moving = true;
            }
        }
        else
            player->is_moving = false;

        
        if(player->is_moving){
            DrawTextureRec(player->run_animation, frames[currentFrame], player->position, WHITE);
        }
        else{
            DrawTextureRec(player->idle_animation, frames[currentFrame], player->position, WHITE);
        }

        EndDrawing();
}

    // Cleanup
    UnloadTexture(player->idle_animation);
    UnloadTexture(player->run_animation);
    CloseAudioDevice();
    CloseWindow();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `new_row = (int)(new_position.y / WALL_HEIGHT); new_col = (int)((new_position.x - CHAR_WIDTH) / WALL_WIDTH);` ( and its 3 friends) generates a `new_position.x` or `new_position..y` outside the [0...21] range or is somehow amiss.  Please Explain these 2 lines of code.